# Linux driver set cancellation point

Tags: linux, kernel, pthreads

I'm writing a simple character device driver for Linux with blocking read() and write().

What I want to do is to set them as cancellation points, so that calling a pthread_cancel on a thread suspended on these functions will cause it to terminate.

How is it possible to set them as cancellation points?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing the kernel driver, all you need to do to make sure that `read()` and `write()` correctly function as cancellation points for userspace is to ensure that they return immediately if a signal is raised on the process while it's waiting in kernel space (either with a short item count or the `EINTR` error).

This generally means using `wait_event_interruptible()` followed by a check for `if (signal_pending(current))`.